# Using VSE. Rendered video and now nothing is showing up.

Tags: edit-mode, video-sequence-editor, video, audio

I've been using the VSE for awhile now and have yet to encounter this problem.

I finished editing my video and clicked render animation. Everything seemed to be going fine. After the video finished rendering I went back through to watch the rendered video and it was just a black screen with no sound. Image overlays I had added to the video would still show up at the appropriate times, but no video or sound.

I tried reloading the file and restarting Blender, but neither of these things works. Can anyone give me any advice? It took me 3 hours to finish editing this video and now it's just gone.

Comment: Is it possible that the video files that the strips are pointing to have been moved or the path has changed in some way?

Comment: You should really provide some more details or upload a blend file for further investigation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preview and rendered video from VSE suddenly shows nothing](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44720/preview-and-rendered-video-from-vse-suddenly-shows-nothing)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/44720/2843

Answer (score 1):

In order for overlays to actually overlay existing video, you need to add an effects strip to tell Blender how to mix it. Generally I use the **alpha over** strip, but there are other options like **alpha under**, **add**, **subtract**, etc).

Otherwise, the VSE takes the top most strip and uses that. Without the effect strip all you'll see is the overlay and nothing but black.

Now if you had some B-roll or stock footage or images that will cover the whole screen, then you wont need a effect strip. Just make sure it's in a higher channel than any other video channel.